# Couldn't find package ruby1.9.3

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-10.04

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, and was trying to install the latest version of Ruby, 1.9.3. However, the command

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.3
```

returns "Couldn't find package ruby1.9.3".

I'm not sure why that is, since it worked with ruby1.9.1.

Comment: Try using rvm instead of apt-get?

Comment: Do you have the brightbox PPA? I use rvm, but IIRC things like [this](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/brightbox_ruby_ng_experimental/lucid/main/base/ruby1.9.3) and [this](http://blog.brightbox.co.uk/posts/next-generation-ruby-packages-for-ubuntu) make me think you need an apt change.

Comment: Simple: Ruby 1.9.3 didn't exist in April, 2010.

Comment: I see... is there any way to update the apt-get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best (at least easier) way to install Ruby in Ubuntu is to install RVM (Ruby Version Manager).

There is a very good and simple guide written by Ryann Bigg [available on his blog](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/).
Just follow each step and it should work!